# Average value calculation

Tags: statistics, average

A company has 2 mines: A and B. The production per person in mine A was 22,6 tons last year, and 27,9 tons in mine B. Last year 60% of the total production came from mine A. The question is the total production of the company per person.

I calculated: $0.6\cdot22.6+0.4\cdot27.9=27.72$. But according to the answer sheet this is not the right answer.

Comment: Am I reading this wrong too many times, or $22,6$ tons/yr per person and $27,9$tons/yer per person does not make sense?

Comment: @bryansis2010: From which point of view? It seems possible as this means less than $100$kg per day per person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed it is not correct. This reminds me of the following problem :
A train runs at $200$kph for $300$km and then at $100$kph for $500$km. What's the average speed of the train?

You can't simply take the average. In your example you need to first calculate the population of each company. Denote them $x_A$ and $x_B$.
Total production from company $A$ is $22.6x_A$.
Total production from company $B$ is $27.9x_B$.
Total production is $22.6x_A + 27.9x_B$.

Hence you have $$22.6x_A = 0.6(22.6x_A + 27.9x_B)\Longrightarrow x_B \approx 0.54x_A$$

If we make such that the total population is $1 = x_A + x_B$, then you have $x_A \approx 0.65$ and $x_B\approx 0.35$.

Hence the average production per person is :
$$0.65\cdot 22.6 + 0.35\cdot 27.9 \approx 24.46$$

Comment: The answer sheet says: $24.46$ tons.

Comment: @user88595. Don't you think that it should be $ 22.6x_A = 0.6\cdot(22.6x_A + 27.9x_B)$

Comment: As Claude has noticed there is an error (it would lead to negative $x_A$!). You have  $22.6x_A = 0.6(22.6x_A + 27.9x_B)$ leading to $x_A=0.649, x_B=0.341,\;$ and the average $0.649\times 22.6+ 0.351\times 27.9 \approx 24.46$